# How to get text instead of value in ASP.NET MVC calculated field for list item?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In the following model class I am attempting to create a calculated field called FullAddress.  I am able to get it to work, but right now it displays the values and not the text for 4 different ID fields.  I would like to display the text instead of the value for the following fields:

- TLRoadDirectionID
- TLRoadTypeID
- VendorAddUnitTypeOneID
- VendorAddUnitTypeTwoID

I received some great help earlier on correctly creating FullAddress, so I know that if I were to change the fields to:

- TLRoadDirection.Direction
- TLRoadType.RdType
- TLUnitTypeOne.UnitType
- TLUnitTypeTwo.UnitType

then it works as expected, but **only** if all of those 4 fields contain a value and are not null or empty.  But these fields will not always have values for each record.

So, how can I modify this calculated field to show the text for each when there is text to show, and not get a null reference exception when any or all of these 4 fields are null or empty?

Below is the class (please let me know if additional information is required):

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web;

namespace VendorMgr.Models
{
public class Vendor
{
    [Display(Name = "Vendor ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    private string _createdBy = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Created By")]
    public string VendorCreatedBy
    {
        get
        {
            return (_createdBy == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name) ? HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name : _createdBy;
        }
        set
        {
            _createdBy = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        }
    }

    private DateTime _createdOn = DateTime.Now;
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Date Created")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime VendorCreatedDt
    {
        get
        {
            return (_createdOn == DateTime.Now) ? DateTime.Now : _createdOn;
        }
        set
        {
            _createdOn = value;
        }
    }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(128)]
    [Display(Name = "Vendor Name")]
    public string VendorName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid phone number")]
    public string VendorPhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    public string VendorEmail { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address Number")]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string VendorAddNum { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Direction")]
    public int? TLRoadDirectionID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Road Name")]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string VendorAddName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Road Type")]
    public int? TLRoadTypeID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Unit Type")]
    public int? VendorAddUnitTypeOneID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Unit")]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string VendorAddUnitOne { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Unit Type")]
    public int? VendorAddUnitTypeTwoID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Unit")]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string VendorAddUnitTwo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Full Address")]
    public string FullAddress
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{VendorAddNum} {TLRoadDirectionID} {VendorAddName} {TLRoadTypeID} {VendorAddUnitTypeOneID} {TLUnitTypeOne.UnitType} {VendorAddUnitOne} {VendorAddUnitTypeTwoID} {VendorAddUnitTwo}";
        }
    }

    [Display(Name = "City")]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string VendorAddCity { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "State")]
    public int? TLStateAcronymnID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Zip Code")]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string VendorZipCode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Country")]
    public int? TLCountryID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Active")]
    public bool VendorActive { get; set; }

    public virtual TLRoadDirection TLRoadDirection { get; set; }
    public virtual TLRoadType TLRoadType { get; set; }
    public virtual TLUnitType TLUnitTypeOne { get; set; }
    public virtual TLUnitType TLUnitTypeTwo { get; set; }
    public virtual TLStateAcronymn TLStateAcronymn { get; set; }
    public virtual TLCountry TLCountry { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: Before you concatenate your properties into a single string, you'll need to check each for null and provide a default value. You'll also need a way to lookup each coded value to get its display string.

Comment: Why not make FullAddress a complex type and let JSON parser sort things out?

Answer (score 0):

```
[Display(Name = "Full Address")]
public string FullAddress
{
    get
    {
        IEnumerable<string> allFields = new[] { VendorAddNum, TLRoadDirectionID, VendorAddName, TLRoadTypeID, VendorAddUnitTypeOneID, TLUnitTypeOne.UnitType, VendorAddUnitOne, VendorAddUnitTypeTwoID, VendorAddUnitTwo };
        return String.Join(" ", allFields.Where<string>(x => x != null));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I still get the null reference exception when I add TLRoadDirection.Direction and the others.

Answer (score 0):

I chose to just handle this in the view instead of the model class.